# Creating a web interface for a database using asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, ajax, entity-framework, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working on an online store web project. Currently, I'm trying to display the content from a database table on a web page.

The table looks like this:
[image]

This is the Model:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Vidly.Models
{
    public class Rental
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Movie Movie { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateRented { get; set; }

        public DateTime? DateReturned { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I've created an API Controller which looks like this

```
using AutoMapper;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using Vidly.Dtos;
using Vidly.Models;
using System.Data.Entity;


namespace Vidly.Controllers.Api
{
    public class RentalsController : ApiController
    {

        private ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public RentalsController()
        {
            _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        // GET /api/rentals
        public IHttpActionResult GetRentals(string query = null)
        {
            var rentalsQuery = _context.Rentals
                .Include(r => r.Customer)
                .Include(r => r.Movie);

            var rentalDtos = rentalsQuery
                .ToList()
                .Select(Mapper.Map<Rental, RentalDto>);

            return Ok(rentalDtos);
        }

        // GET /api/rentals/1
        public IHttpActionResult GetRental(int id)
        {
            var rental = _context.Rentals.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Id == id);

            if (rental == null)
                return NotFound();

            return Ok(Mapper.Map<Rental, RentalDto>(rental));
        }
    }
}
```

and another Controller which looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Vidly.Models;
using System.Data.Entity;
using Vidly.ViewModels;

namespace Vidly.Controllers
{
    public class RentalsController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _context;

        [Authorize(Roles = RoleName.CanManageMovies)]
        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            if (User.IsInRole(RoleName.CanManageMovies))
                return View("Index");
            else
                return View("Home");
        }
        public ActionResult New()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            var rental = _context.Rentals.Include(r => r.Movie).Include(r => r.Customer).SingleOrDefault(r => r.Id == id);

            if (rental == null)
                return HttpNotFound();

            return View(rental);
        }

    }
}
```

Finally, the cshtml file looks something like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<Vidly.Models.Rental>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Rentals";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>Rentals</h2>

<table id="rentals" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Customer</th>
            <th>Movie</th>
            <th>Date Rented</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>

@section scripts
{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var table = $("#rentals").DataTable({
                ajax: {
                    url: "/api/rentals",
                    dataSrc: ""
                },
                columns: [
                    {
                        data: "customer.name"
                    },
                    {
                        data: "movie.name"
                    },
                    {
                        data: "daterented"
                    }
                ]
            });

        });
    </script>
}
```

The problem is that whenever I'm trying to access the web page, I'm getting this error message 5 times, for every entry in the table:

> DataTables warning: table id=rentals - Requested unknown parameter
>   'daterented' for row 0, column 2. For more information about this
>   error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

The table looks like this:
[image]

And the XML file (available when accessing https://localhost:44300/api/rentals) from where the data for the table should be fetched looks like this:
[image]

I would be very glad if you could help me out with this problem!
Many thanks!

Comment: Could you tell us what is the response from the server. You can check it in the network tag

Comment: Yes. Here's a link to an image of it. https://ibb.co/nmFO2a

Comment: Well you are calling this method: `/api/rentals` but i can't see it. This should be the correct method: `GetRentals`?

Comment: The API response doesn't have properties `customer.name`or `movie.name`. The datatable is not able to find these in the datasource if it that's why you see this error. Recommended way is to use json format  for returning data from API so that jQuery have easy parsing of it.

Comment: Fixed that. Updated the post. Still not being able to display the "daterented".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems that i had the Camelcase enabled.

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case

Therefore, instead of

```
columns: [
                {
                    data: "customer.name"
                },
                {
                    data: "movie.name"
                },
                {
                    data: "daterented"
                }
            ]
```

My code should have been

```
columns: [
                {
                    data: "customer.name"
                },
                {
                    data: "movie.name"
                },
                {
                    data: "dateRented"
                }
            ]
```